# Determine the values for a for which the set of matrices are linear independent

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I wm given a set of matricies:

$S=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\ 
1 & a \\ 
    \end{array}
\right), \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
-1 & 0 \\ 
a & 1 \\ 
    \end{array}
\right),
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 0 \\ 
1 & 3 \\ 
    \end{array}
\right)
$

and $a\in  \mathbb R$. I am told to find all the values of $a$ such that $S$ is a linearly independent set.

That would imply the linear combination of those $3$ matrices should equal $0$. Namely,

$
\alpha_1\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\ 
1 & a \\ 
    \end{array}
\right) + \alpha_2\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
-1 & 0 \\ 
a & 1 \\ 
    \end{array}
\right) + \alpha_3\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 0 \\ 
1 & 3 \\ 
    \end{array}
\right)=0$

should be true. Now, I can write the set of matrices as a single matrix, or basically,

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -1 & 2\\ 
0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & a & 1\\
a & 1 & 3\\ 
    \end{array}
\right)$

I am stuck at this point. How would I find the values of a? I believe I can row reduce this matrix and do something but I am not really sure how to go about it from here. I got the suggestion that I could simply take out the 0 row from this matrix and compute the determinant but I am not sure how I would justify that. Is that even valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done a good job, putting them in a matrix. If you write it in a different order, you get

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -1 & 2\\ 
a & 1 & 3\\
1 & a & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0\\ 
    \end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\alpha_1\\ 
\alpha_2\\
\alpha_3\\
    \end{array}
\right)=0$

Now, you should search for the null-space of the matrix. If the null-space is only the vector $\{0\}$, then columns of the matrix are independent. Also notice that you can totally ignore the last row, as any combination of it gives zero anyway.

A nonzero vector $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)^T$ is in the null-space of the matrix, if and only if it is in the null-space of

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -1 & 2\\ 
a & 1 & 3\\
1 & a & 1\\
    \end{array}\right)$

But this is a square matrix and we can use the determinant for it, in order to find values $a$, for which the columns are independent.

Comment: Aha. Thank you. I think I got it now. If I were to take this matrix back and write a system of equations then I would have a 0 for some of my equations and since any scalar times 0 is 0, I can just disregard that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

They are exactly the values that make that matrix of rank $3$. Id est, exactly the values of $a$ such that $$\det\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&2\\0&0&0\\1&a&1\end{pmatrix}\ne0\vee \det\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&2\\0&0&0\\a&1&3\end{pmatrix}\ne0\vee\det\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&2\\1&a&1\\a&1&3\end{pmatrix}\ne0\vee \det\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\1&a&1\\a&1&3\end{pmatrix}\ne0$$

Since all these determinants except the third one are $0$, this is equivalent to the inequation $$\det\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&2\\1&a&1\\a&1&3\end{pmatrix}\ne0$$

Comment: Sorry but do you mind explaining what you did. I'm not seeing how you showed the row of 0's does not matter in computing the determinant.

Comment: @SubhashisChakraborty Since the rank is the largest order of an invertible square submatrix, you are looking for the values of $a$ which satisfy at least one of those four inequations. Three of them never hold (because a matrix with a line of zeros has determinant $0$), so you are left with just one equation.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way: You can arrange the matrices as columns for the $4\times 3$ matrix as you did, or you could also arrange them like this:
$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0\\ 
1 & -1 & 2\\
1 & a & 1\\
a & 1 & 3\\ 
    \end{array}
\right)$. The only thing that matters, is that the $(i,j)_{th}$ entry of every matrix is in the same horizontal line. From here I believe it is easier to see why you can justify deleting the zero row?